# How come my css3 animations don't work in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First, I use JQuery to set the background image. Then, I add the class "gridbouncer", which has animation functions inside.

```
$(function(){
$(".grid_doc_holder").each(function(e){
      imageurl = $(this).attr("data-image");
      $(this).css('background', 'url(' + imageurl + ') no-repeat 50% 50% #000');
      $(this).addClass("gridbouncer");
       });
});
```

This is my CSS:

```
@keyframes bounce-background {
    from {
        background-position: top;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: bottom;
    }
    to {
        background-position: top;
    }
}
.gridbouncer {
    animation-name: bounce-background;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Comment: Dumb question: Which browsers/renders currently support `@keyframes`? A quick Google seem to indicate it's only Webkit, and then only as `@-webkit-keyframes`. Also I wouldn't be surprised, if it doesn't work for dynamically applied styles. Does it work when you set background and class directly in the HTML?

Comment: Why not just use jQuery to do the whole animation as well?

Comment: JQuery is super slow because it doesn't use the hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need -webkit prefixes on all these animation settings (and will need a -moz and -o in those browsers when they support animations.)